# How to check how many cores PySpark uses?

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark, virtualbox, cpu-cores

I have installed VirtualBox(Ubuntu 18.04.2 64-bit) and PySpark 2.4.0. When I created a VB I put 4 CPUs to be max.

How am I supposed to check how many cores Spark is using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends on the [master URL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) that describes what runtime environment (*cluster manager*) to use.

Since this is such a low-level infrastructure-oriented thing you can find the answer by querying a `SparkContext` instance.

E.g. if it's `local[*]` that would mean that you want to use as many CPUs (the star part) as are available on the local JVM.

```
$ ./bin/pyspark
Python 2.7.15 (default, Feb 19 2019, 09:17:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
...
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.15 (default, Feb 19 2019 09:17:37)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> print sc.master
local[*]
>>> print sc.defaultParallelism
8
```

Comment: Thank you Jacek for the answer. One more question (I know that is the one that is quiet frequent...But I didn't find an answer). When I run ./bin/pyspark I get bash: ./bin/pyspark No such file or directory. How to overcome that?

Comment: Where do you _"When I run ./bin/pyspark"_? What's the directory? What's the OS?

Comment: I tried to run it in home directory but also in folder where spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7 and also in subfolder of that folder in bin and python and everywhere I get mistake...

Comment: Can you `ls -l bin/pyspark` while in `spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7`?

Comment: So when I enter in that folder and type that I get the following:   -rwxr-xr-x 1 name name 2987 окт 29 07:36 bin/pyspark

Comment: Looks OK. What happens when you do `./bin/pyspark` while in `spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7`?

Comment: ./bin/pyspark: line 45: python:command not found          env: 'python': No such file or directory

Comment: You should then install `python`. Since I don't use pyspark I don't even know where in the docs they say that you should.

Comment: Can you execute `python` on command line? You should have the executable in `PATH`.

Comment: python no, python3 yes

Comment: Well, you have to symlink it then. I'm not sure if pyspark works with Python3.

Comment: How did you make the code ran with python3 then since you have troubles executing pyspark?

Comment: I'm having Windows 10 os,so I created VirtualBox and installed Ubuntu18.04.2(64-bit) then I installed Python 3.6.7, jupyther notebook(where I run code), Java 10.0.2, Scala 2.11.12, Py4J, Spark 2.4.0

Comment: Please ask a separate question to keep the discussion in a proper place.

Comment: Okey, thank you very much on such exhausting answering and time you spent on this.